# approx_count_distinct pyspark agg function with rsd argument in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

In databricks, when I run approx_count_distinct function with 'rsd' argument, it returns the error message. It works without this argument.

**Dataset**

```
+-------------+----------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|
+-------------+----------+------+
|James        |Sales     |3000  |
|Michael      |Sales     |4600  |
|Robert       |Sales     |4100  |
|Maria        |Finance   |3000  |
|James        |Sales     |3000  |
|Scott        |Finance   |3300  |
|Jen          |Finance   |3900  |
|Jeff         |Marketing |3000  |
|Kumar        |Marketing |2000  |
|Saif         |Sales     |4100  |
+-------------+----------+------+
```

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import approx_count_distinct 
df.agg(approx_count_distinct(col("salary"))).alias("salaryDistinct")
```

**Error message**

```
py4j.Py4JException: Method approx_count_distinct([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your error. Just wondering, what is the output you see for `print(col)` (in case if you have overridden that function)?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the above and got the same error.

[image]

The above error occurs when **we give the `rsd` value as integer**. As per [pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct.html#pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct) `rsd` value should be `float`.

**Desired result when float is given.**

[image]

Comment: That's great to know. Actually, I got this code from 'Databricks Certified Associate Developer for Apache Spark 3.0' mock-up test question number 31.

It considers the following code correct ```df.agg(approx_count_distinct(col("salary"), 0)).alias("divisionDistinct")```

Comment: Yeah, but as 0 is an integer I got same error. as per this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct.html#pyspark.sql.functions.approx_count_distinct) maximum relative standard deviation allowed (default = 0.05). For `rsd < 0.01`, it is more efficient to use `countDistinct()`.

Comment: I emailed databricks that their mock-up test is wrong. Thanks, Rakesh.